# Fixing my box inside a box

Tags: html

I currently have a box inside a box, but it is not centered around the text.
I'd like to center the box around the text so that the box does not run over empty space:

http://jsfiddle.net/infoed/nvVBU/ (css is in the jdfiddle) :

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fumblr.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
             <li><img src="img/toplogo.png"></li>
             <li> <a> Fumblr </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="box">
            <img src="img/heart.svg" height="18" width="18" />
            <div class="userid">DogBountyHunter27</div>
            <div class="headline">Been 10 Days off bread. Want to die</div>
            <p>Is there any doubt that cats are awesome? We love cats, and being Mashable and all, we know a thing or two about them. But is it even possible to put our feelings about cats into infographic form? You be the judge. Undaunted by such a Herculean task...</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="img/heart.svg" height="18" width="18"  />
            <div class="userid">Vader2307</div>
            <div class="headline">Hilarious Link of Bill Gates Jumping over a chair</div>
            <p>Type an address into your phone, and up will pop a step-by-step route from where you are to where you want to be. This is, in its way, magic. But it's magic that has, at this point, been rubbed and polished into a simple fact of life. The ease with...  </p>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="img/heart.svg" height="18" width="18" />
            <div class="userid">ShaqAttack</div>
            <div class="headline">Is Insanity Wolf bad for the meme community?</div>
            <p>Is there any doubt that cats are awesome? We love cats, and being Mashable and all, we know a thing or two about them. But is it even possible to put our feelings about cats into infographic form? You be the judge. Undaunted by such a Herculean task...</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="img/heart.svg" height="18" width="18" />
            <div class="userid">Jimmy Two Times</div>
            <div class="headline">Fax machines making a comeback in Williamsburg</div>
            <p>Is there any doubt that cats are awesome? We love cats, and being Mashable and all, we know a thing or two about them. But is it even possible to put our feelings about cats into infographic form? You be the judge. Undaunted by such a Herculean task...</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="img/heart.svg" height="18" width="18" />
            <div class="userid">SmoothieFanatic</div>
            <div class="headline">Fifth Grader Expelled for bringing Siracha to school</div>
            <p>Is there any doubt that cats are awesome? We love cats, and being Mashable and all, we know a thing or two about them. But is it even possible to put our feelings about cats into infographic form? You be the judge. Undaunted by such a Herculean task...</p>
        </div>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What div are you referring to when talking about boxes? box and headline? content and box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about the "headline" divs. If so, just change the divs to spans. This will wrap the the words with no excess whitespace on the end.

```
<div class="headline">HEADLINE HERE</div>
```

Change to:

```
<span class="headline">HEADLINE HERE</span>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: now the article that goes underneath the boxted text is outside the box! Your fix did properly wrap the headline though!

Comment: In your stylesheet for .box change height to 'min-height'. This will make it able to expand with the articles.

Comment: Can you please add a new JsFiddle to what you have now? Are you saying the box is displaying over the text and covering it?

Comment: You changed 'height: 200px;' to 'height: min-height;' when it needs to be: 'min-height: 200px;'

Comment: Thank you! Using the same jsfiddle from 5 minutes ago, how can I pad the text underneath the headline so its not so close together? Also, is there a way to clean up my nav bar? It's horrible. If i need to make a new question, I will.

Comment: Add '.box .userid {padding-bottom: 5px;}' to your stylesheet to add room under the userid. If you're talking about the padding the paragraph so that the words aren't directly on top of each other then add 'line-height: 200%;' in your '.box .p' section of your stylesheet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/infoed/UF4V9/: Is there a way to cleanup this navbar so it's not unsightly? I've also added the .box .userid but the padding is not working

Comment: The padding looks like it's working for me. Refer to my most recent comment to add line-height padding for the paragraph if that's what you need.

As for you navbar, the styling is all up to your preference.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to change the navbar styling to an acceptable output. I added auto height and width but it did nothing. I'm trying to get the the picture and logo to big of similar size in a similar stripe (background color) bar at the top

Comment: Don't set the height or width at all. Just add the image, and it will stretch the div.

Comment: no change. Thanks for your help but I just want a simple navbar. This is a huge block of blue with a large pic and a small word

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/infoed/UF4V9/ ... just a horrible navbar. I just want something half that size with the pic and a larger piece of text (fumblr) right next to it.

Comment: wow..it works in jsfiddle but not in chrome when i take the code.
Thanks for all your help. Don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of css cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Well, it's not working in any browser. Just jsfiddle's rendering